# How do I stay on org's "bleeding edge"?

Tags: org-mode

I'm curious how I get my emacs to use the git org-mode repository. I have followed the instructions [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#keeping-current-with-Org-mode-development). Now I have a `~/elisp/org-mode/` directory but I'm not sure how to get emacs to use this version of org. Issuing `M-x org-version` yields

```
Org mode version 9.0 (9.0-elpa @ /home/brian/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20161102/)
```

So, my emacs is using the org package from `elpa`. How do I get my emacs using the git version and not the elpa version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is delete the elpa package (use `M-x list-packages`, find org-mode, type `d` to mark it for deletion and `x` to execute the changes), and add the new directory to your load path, e.g.

```
(setq load-path (cons "~/elisp/org-mode" load-path))
(require 'org-mode)
```

but this is untested. The document you linked to says that the [elpa](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages) archive is updated daily, and I don't see any need to change faster than that.

Comment: You don't even need to delete the other `org-mode` versions.  As long as `~/elisp/org-mode` is first in the `load-path` it will be found before the others.

Comment: @erikstokes I agree that as long as the right org-mode is the first one found in the load path all will work and the OP doesn't need to delete any others. However how do I explain the interactions between the package manager setting the load-path, when the package is loaded, and where the OP adds the extra lines? Much simpler to just delete any other copies which will otherwise be a source for confusion.